# MySQL Nested Select with Joined Table

Tags: mysql, select, nested-select

I'm assuming there's a way to do this with MySQL but my experience with relational databases is limited so I'm hoping to get some guidaince.

I have a `users`, `registrations` and `user_registrations` table. I'm want to create a `SELECT` query on my `users` table that does a nested select that counts the `user_registrations` for that user.

So for example, I would be looking to have something like this:

`SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT() FROM user_registrations WHERE users.user_id = user_registrations.user_id) FROM users`

I think my understanding of nested selects is off and I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group and include all columns you select from the `users` table into your `group by` clause also

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, COUNT(r.user_id) 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_registrations r ON u.user_id = r.user_id 
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```